# How do I log into DrawSomething after I close my Facebook account?

Tags: draw-something

I used to sign into DrawSomething using my Facebook account but then I closed and deleted my Facebook account and since then haven't been able to log into DrawSomething.

Numerous password requests using the email account I used for my Facebook login have gone ignored so how do I get back into my account or is my 400 point game lost forever?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the messages went to your spam folder you'll have to contact support. I believe they were receptive to such problems in the past, so there is a good chance they'll help you.

Comment: I agree I think you can't recover it by design. So try contacting them and see where it'll get you.